# Batch Job Scheduler

Tags: macos, homebrew, ssh

This might be weird to ask, since in all these years I've never used a Mac as a "remote scheduler", but this is what I need now.

Can you recommend a **batch job scheduler**?

What I need is to login via `ssh`, launch commands and be able to exit from the shell. When the system will be able, the scheduler will run my job (usually a shell script). It would be cool to have the system send an email when it finishes.

I have seen `screen` or `at`, but it's not what I'd really need (`at` requires a time, and `screen` is just a shell that can be detached). With these tools I need to manually schedule jobs. I've used some clustering facilities under linux, using `qsub` to submit jobs, and it was neat.

However, installing `torque` might be really cumbersome, and I am stuck with it. It needs `openssl-devel` and I don't know how to install that, I thought using `homebrew` and installing `openssl` (with the correct `$PATH`) would be sufficient, but it's not.

Do you have any "easy" to setup batch scheduler recommendation?

Thanks!

Comment: You question is about  a scheduler and yet you said, ..."`at`, but it's not what I'd really need (`at` requires a time"... Well that's ironic!  Isn't the very nature of a scheduler to do something at a set or given date and time?

Comment: Sort of. A batch scheduler will execute commands subsequently without prior knowledge on the time it will take. The at command requires a time, so I need to estimate it, and I will always fail in this :)

Comment: So in your question, why didn't you just simply say you're looking for an _event driven batch job scheduler_? :)

Comment: Because it's not event driven usually, as Torque, but I didn't see the source to know how it determines when and where to execute something. It doesn't compile, I won't read the docs until it does :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [List of job scheduler software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software) at [WikipediA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) which support *event driven* job scheduling and lists OS X as a Platform was only one package, [JobServer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JobServer) by [Grand Logic](http://www.grandlogic.com/content/html_docs/products-jobserver.shtml).

Being that this info is from WikipediA, this of course by no means is necessarily a complete and or authoritative list, however it's a place to start.